# Why extend Exception class?

Tags: java

I've encountered a class which extends Exception :

```
public class MyException extends Exception
{
    public MyException()
    {
        super();
    }

    public MyException(final String argMessage, final Throwable argCause)
    {
        super(argMessage, argCause);
    }

    public MyException(final String argMessage)
    {
        super(argMessage);
    }

    public MyException(final Throwable argCause)
    {
        super(argCause);
    }


}
```

Is it not pointless extening exception this way since all of the overriding constructors are just calling the super class Exception ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subclassing Exception in Java: when isn't a custom message "good enough"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366425/subclassing-exception-in-java-when-isnt-a-custom-message-good-enough)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it is not pointless. You can `catch` the specific exception this way and handle it specifically, rather then catching a general `Exception`, which might not be handled in all cases.

With this, you can do:

```
try { 
  foo();
} catch (MyException e) {
  handleMyException(e);
}
```

Which is not possible if you do not know how to handle a general `Exception`, but you can handle `MyException` better.

It is also improves readability - it is better to declare a method as `throws MyException` (with better name usually) then `throws Exception` - you know what can go wrong much better this way.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there's a reason. It allows you to differentiate the type of your exceptions.

Suppose this following code:

```
try {
    // some instructions
} catch (MyFirstException firstException) {
    // Handler for the first exception
} catch (MySecondException secondException) {
    // Handler for the first exception
} catch (Exception exception) {
    // Handler for all other exceptions
}
```

Event if the `MyFirstException` and `MySecondException` inherit from Exception and override all methods, you can distinguish them in the catch blocks. So, you can have different handlers for both exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

when you would always do a `catch (Exception e)` you would actually catch each and every subclass of `Exception`, this specifically also applies to `RuntimeException`s which you usually don't want to catch. This can only be made worse by catching `Throwable`